# Why and What purpose use this <?= ?> syntax in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

Why and What purpose use this `<?= ?>` syntax in cakephp

code example

```
<h1>
    Getting All bookmarks with certain Tags:
    <?= $this->Text->toList( $tags ); ?>
</h1>

<section>
    <?php foreach ( $bookmarks as $bookmark ) { ?>
        <article>
            <h4><?= $this->Html->link( $bookmark->title, $bookmark->url ); ?></h4>
            <small><?= h( $bookmark->url ) ?></small>
            <?= $this->Text->autoParagraph( $bookmark->description ); ?>
        </article>
    <?php } ?>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4):

It is the short echo syntax. It is a built-in part of PHP not specific to the CakePHP framework. However, the [CakePHP coding standards](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html#short-echo) state that it should be used in template files instead of `<?php echo ...`.

Comment: Thank you @Don't Panic ! I got answer!